# Celery - print messages are printed twice to console

Tags: python, celery

Here is the file where celery application is defined:

```py
from celery import Celery

from constants import TASKS_FILE_NAMES

celery_app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

for filename in TASKS_FILE_NAMES:
    print(filename)
    celery_app.autodiscover_tasks(['units'], related_name=filename[:-3], force=True)
```

and there is constants.py in the same package:

```py
import os

TASKS_DIR = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "units")
TASKS_FILE_NAMES = [file for file in os.listdir(TASKS_DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(TASKS_DIR, file)) and file != '__init__.py']
```

I also have `/units` folder inside that package consisting of files where tasks are located. They're just python files in which I'm scraping some websites using python requests and BeautifulSoup. Each of that file has its main() function decorated with `@celery_app.task(name=__file__)`

Here is `/units/__init__.py`:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

update2 = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent
sys.path.append(str(update2))
```

When I run celery with `celery --app celeryapp worker --loglevel=INFO` command, filenames are printed twice. In fact, everything I've tried is being printed twice, as if the file is being executed twice. What could cause such behavior?

Comment:  please share some more information. What does the `/units` directory look like? And what file names are being printed?

Comment: updated with additional info

Comment: Hm I cannot reproduce without Celery, so it must be related. My suggestion is to add some timestamps to the prints, along with a new print timestamp before the loop. This will let you know if the entire thing is executed twice or concurrently etc.

Comment: Okay, I just found out reason for that behavior, in each of my scraping script file I import this celery_app (from parent folder) and executing celery_app.autodiscover_tasks function is importing each and every one of them again. When I comment out that line of code everyting works fine but, why does it print only twice and not more (11 files in /units)?

Comment: I guess python won't re-execute same file twice if imported more than once